# Is PREEMPT_DYNAMIC causing Ubuntu to freeze?

Tags: 22.04, freeze

My Ubuntu is freezing (not responding, nothing including mouse/keyboard and desktop shows old time). It happens once/twice a week. I have not figured out the actual culprit, though but the logs contain the following error messages:

- Kernel Log

  ```
  $ dmesg -T
  ...
  ...
  ...
  [Fri May 19 13:50:42 2023] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20220331/psparse-529)
  [Fri May 19 13:50:42 2023] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20220331/dsfield-184)
  [Fri May 19 13:50:42 2023] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20220331/dswload2-477)

  [Fri May 19 13:50:42 2023] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_DSM]

  [Fri May 19 13:50:42 2023] Initialized Arguments for Method [_DSM]:  (4 arguments defined for method invocation)
  [Fri May 19 13:50:42 2023]   Arg0:   00000000ed5b63f3 <Obj>           Buffer(16) 75 0B A5 D4 C7 65 F7 46
  [Fri May 19 13:50:42 2023]   Arg1:   000000009f563d37 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000102
  [Fri May 19 13:50:42 2023]   Arg2:   00000000aa83d0d2 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000010
  [Fri May 19 13:50:42 2023]   Arg3:   00000000e5707ac8 <Obj>           Buffer(4) 00 00 50 4F
  ...
  ...
  ...
  ```
- Sys Log

  ```
  $ grep -i "error" /var/log/syslog
  ...
  ...
  ...
  May 19 13:50:44 asus gnome-session[1597]: gnome-session-binary[1597]: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_bus_get_sync: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed
  May 19 13:50:44 asus gnome-session-binary[1597]: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_bus_get_sync: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed
  May 19 13:50:44 asus gsd-sharing[1665]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
  May 19 13:50:44 asus gnome-shell[1612]: Error looking up permission: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.NotFound: No entry for geolocation
  May 19 13:50:44 asus gnome-shell[1612]: JS ERROR: Failed to initialize fprintd service: Gio.IOErrorEnum: GDBus.Error:net.reactivated.Fprint.Error.NoSuchDevice: No devices available#012asyncCallback@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/core/overrides/Gio.js:114:23
  May 19 13:50:45 asus gsd-sharing[1665]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
  May 19 13:50:45 asus hpfax: [1895]: error: Failed to create /var/spool/cups/tmp/.hplip
  May 19 13:50:50 asus /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2094]: #011(WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
  May 19 13:50:52 asus gnome-session[2244]: gnome-session-binary[2244]: GnomeDesktop-WARNING: Could not create transient scope for PID 2379: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnixProcessIdUnknown: Process with ID 2379 does not exist.
  May 19 13:50:52 asus gnome-session-binary[2244]: GnomeDesktop-WARNING: Could not create transient scope for PID 2379: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnixProcessIdUnknown: Process with ID 2379 does not exist.
  May 19 13:50:52 asus gsd-color[1668]: failed to set xrandr-LG Electronics-LG HDR 4K-76144 color transform matrix: failed to load file: Error opening file /home/ravi/.local/share/icc/edid-8f7ad153e8611fa231dc1672517ef7af.icc: Permission denied
  May 19 13:50:52 asus gnome-shell[2263]: Error looking up permission: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.NotFound: No entry for geolocation
  May 19 13:50:52 asus gsd-color[1668]: failed to set xrandr-LG Electronics-LG HDR 4K-76144 color transform matrix: failed to load file: Error opening file /home/ravi/.local/share/icc/edid-8f7ad153e8611fa231dc1672517ef7af.icc: Permission denied
  May 19 13:50:53 asus gsd-sharing[1665]: Error releasing name org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sharing: The connection is closed
  May 19 13:50:53 asus gsd-print-notif[1671]: Error releasing name org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.PrintNotifications: The connection is closed
  May 19 13:50:53 asus gsd-rfkill[1673]: Error releasing name org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Rfkill: The connection is closed
  May 19 13:50:53 asus gsd-screensaver[1682]: Error releasing name org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver: The connection is closed
  May 19 13:50:53 asus gsd-sound[1687]: Error releasing name org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sound: The connection is closed
  May 19 13:50:53 asus gsd-housekeepin[1696]: Error releasing name org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Housekeeping: The connection is closed
  May 19 13:51:02 asus snap-store[2514]: not handling error failed for action refresh: E: Failed to fetch http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease  #012E: Failed to fetch http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/InRelease  #012E: Failed to fetch http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/InRelease  #012E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/InRelease  #012E: Failed to fetch file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-11-7-local/InRelease  #012E: Failed to fetch file:/var/cudnn-local-repo-ubuntu2204-8.8.0.121/InRelease  #012E: Failed to fetch http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu/dists/disco/InRelease  #012E: Failed to fetch https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/InRelease  #012E: Failed to fetch http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code/dists/stable/InRelease  #012E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
  May 19 13:51:06 asus pulseaudio[1929]: GetManagedObjects() failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.TimedOut: Failed to activate service 'org.bluez': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
  May 19 13:52:08 asus google-chrome.desktop[5432]: [5426:5490:0519/135208.668720:ERROR:entity_annotator_native_library.cc(317)] Failed to create entity annotator: Failure to open metadata table of slice 'global', status = 'UNKNOWN: Failure to open metadata random access file with open sourced levedb '/home/ravi/.config/google-chrome/Profile 1/optimization_guide_prediction_model_downloads/fefbdd2f-f3f8-4e65-8d03-3142006f4408/global-entities_metadata', status = 'IO error: /home/ravi/.config/google-chrome/Profile 1/optimization_guide_prediction_model_downloads/fefbdd2f-f3f8-4e65-8d03-3142006f4408/global-entities_metadata: Invalid argument''. Failed to initialize SenseLevelDbModel while creating EntityAnnotator:
  May 19 13:55:18 asus google-chrome.desktop[5432]: [libprotobuf ERROR ../../third_party/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/message_lite.cc:133] Can't parse message of type "safe_browsing.ClientDownloadRequest" because it is missing required fields: (cannot determine missing fields for lite message)
  May 19 14:22:21 asus google-chrome.desktop[5432]: [5426:5426:0519/142221.380716:ERROR:fallback_task_provider.cc(124)] Every renderer should have at least one task provided by a primary task provider. If a "Renderer" fallback task is shown, it is a bug. If you have repro steps, please file a new bug and tag it as a dependency of crbug.com/739782.
  May 19 14:32:11 asus google-chrome.desktop[5432]: [5475:5475:0519/143211.778438:ERROR:shared_image_manager.cc(217)] SharedImageManager::ProduceSkia: Trying to Produce a Skia representation from a non-existent mailbox.
  May 19 14:50:41 asus systemd[1]: Starting Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled...
  May 19 14:50:41 asus whoopsie-upload-all[10487]: ERROR: whoopsie.path is not enabled
  May 19 14:50:41 asus systemd[1]: Failed to start Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled.
  May 19 15:06:57 asus vlc[11117]: Qt: Session management error: Could not open network socket
  May 19 15:07:05 asus org.gnome.Nautilus[11117]: [00007f4bd8001f30] glconv_vaapi_x11 gl error: vaCreateSurfaces: attribute not supported
  May 19 15:07:05 asus org.gnome.Nautilus[11117]: [00007f4be004b840] main video output error: video output creation failed
  May 19 15:07:05 asus org.gnome.Nautilus[11117]: [00007f4becc21ff0] main decoder error: failed to create video output
  May 19 15:19:48 asus google-chrome.desktop[5432]: [5476:5482:0519/151948.755078:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(992)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
  May 19 15:27:10 asus google-chrome.desktop[5432]: Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file: No such file: (null)
  May 19 15:51:18 asus gnome-shell[2263]: JS ERROR: Failed to initialize fprintd service: Gio.IOErrorEnum: GDBus.Error:net.reactivated.Fprint.Error.NoSuchDevice: No devices available#012asyncCallback@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/core/overrides/Gio.js:114:23
  May 19 16:25:03 asus tracker-miner-f[1996]: SQLite error: database disk image is malformed (errno: Bad file descriptor)
  ...
  ...
  ...
  ```

Based on the Google search, the `AE_ALREADY_EXISTS` error is reported in the case of an old graphics driver. However, I am using new drivers in my Ubuntu. Please see below:

- NVIDIA utility

  ```
  $ nvidia-smi 
  Fri May 19 16:25:15 2023       
  +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
  | NVIDIA-SMI 515.65.01    Driver Version: 515.65.01    CUDA Version: 11.7     |
  |-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
  | GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
  | Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
  |                               |                      |               MIG M. |
  |===============================+======================+======================|
  |   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  On   | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
  |  0%   50C    P3    41W / 350W |    959MiB / 24576MiB |      4%      Default |
  |                               |                      |                  N/A |
  +-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

  +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
  | Processes:                                                                  |
  |  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
  |        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
  |=============================================================================|
  |    0   N/A  N/A      2094      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                508MiB |
  |    0   N/A  N/A      2263      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell               61MiB |
  |    0   N/A  N/A      5035      G   ...RendererForSitePerProcess       99MiB |
  |    0   N/A  N/A      5475      G   ...025141959637500949,262144      286MiB |
  +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
  ```
- Cuda compiler

  ```
  $ nvcc --version
  nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
  Copyright (c) 2005-2022 NVIDIA Corporation
  Built on Wed_Jun__8_16:49:14_PDT_2022
  Cuda compilation tools, release 11.7, V11.7.99
  Build cuda_11.7.r11.7/compiler.31442593_0
  ```
- GPU name

  ```
  $ nvidia-smi --query-gpu=name --format=csv,noheader
  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3090
  ```

Surprisingly, the OS is using `PREEMPT_DYNAMIC` instead of `SMP`. However, I did not perform any kernel customization. Thus I expect it to be the default in Ubuntu, i.e., `SMP`. See below, please:

- Kernel info

  ```
  $ uname -a
  Linux asus 5.19.0-41-generic #42~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Apr 18 17:40:00 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
  ```
- OS info

  ```
  $ lsb_release -a
  No LSB modules are available.
  Distributor ID: Ubuntu
  Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
  Release:    22.04
  Codename:   jammy
  ```
- GCC info

  ```
  $ gcc --version
  gcc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.3.0
  Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
  This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
  warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
  ```

I am looking for suggestions to prevent my Ubuntu from freezing. I am wondering if the `PREEMPT_DYNAMIC` setting could be the cause of the issue.